# Beautiful Soup Login with Python 3 - What's the POST url of this form?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to log into a site I want to grab some data from.  The scraping bit I am good with but I am struggling with logging in.  The bit I think is causing me the issue is that the form POST is to here:

```
/@s/login/?redirectto=%2F
```

How do I construct the full url as I don't know what @s means? And do I need to worry about the redirect bit?

Thanks,
Johnny

Comment: It's probably a local path, just prepend the protocol/domain and you'll have the full URL. The `%2F` part is a URL encoded slash that redirects to the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

No idea still what this means so feel free to answer but by trial and error this worked for me:

```
https://www.example.com/@s/login/?redirectto=%2F
```